# gnuplot png white on black

Tags: png, gnuplot

In gnuplot-4.2.6 I can produce a nice white on black image using

```
set term png medium x000000 xffffff
set output 'file.png'
plot x
```

This produces a png file with a black background and white axes, axis labels, titles, legend text, etc.

The new gnuplot-5.0.1 complains about the above 'set term' command saying "obsolete color option".  The closest I can come to getting an image which is white on black is to set the background to black with

```
set term png medium background '#ffffff'
set output 'file.png'
plot x
```

but this just sets the background to black without setting the axes, axis labels etc. to white.

Does anyone know how I can get white on black png images in the latest version of gnuplot?

Comment: The `png` terminal itself is obsolete. Try using `pngcairo` which might allow you to do what you want. I can't check myself since I don't use gnuplot-5.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  I'm using CentOS-6.6 where having cairo and cairo-devel installed makes no difference to the config and build of gnuplot.

Answer (score 8):

These color options for the png terminal were removed with version 4.6. The log says about this: [This mechanism is totally obsolete except for setting the background color](http://gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnuplot/gnuplot/term/gd.trm?r1=1.145&r2=1.146).

Since version 4.6.0 you can (but also must) set the `linecolor` and `textcolor` of every part explicitely:

```
set terminal pngcairo background rgb 'black'
set xlabel 'ylabel' tc rgb 'white'
set ylabel 'xlabel' tc rgb 'white'
set border lc rgb 'white'
set key tc rgb 'white'

set linetype 1 lc rgb 'white'
set output 'bw.png'
plot x lc 1, x**2 lc 1
```

[image]

If you only need those settings for some pictures you could move several parts to some kind of config file `black-and-white.gp' with the content

```
set macros
bg = 'background rgb "black"'
white = 'textcolor rgb "white"'
set xlabel @white
set ylabel @white
set linetype 11 lc rgb 'white'
set border lc 11
set key @white
```

In the actual plotting file you use it like

```
load 'black-and-white.gp'
set terminal pngcairo @bg
set xlabel 'xlabel'
set ylabel 'ylabel'

set output 'bw.png'
plot x lc 11, x**2 lc 11
```

Comment: man i'm glad they remove this obsolete option and we get to do it explicitely instead, hacking around in a script that worked for over a decade. obsoleteness can't stop us!

Comment: There's also `set bars lc rgb 'white'` for plots with error bars.